# How to set regular expression parameter constraints for Route::group in Laravel 4?

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

For simple routes I know I can user `where` statement. But what about parameters in Route::group() prefix

```
<?php

Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@profile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo/{bar}'], function() {
    // ...
})->where('bar', '[0-9a-Z]+'); // this won't work
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the box the laravel router doesn't support this. You can use the [Enhanced Router](https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) package from Jason Lewis or a [fork that enables support for Laravel 4.2](https://github.com/hamedb89/enhanced-router)

Alternatively you can do it yourself. You could basically add the where condition to every route inside the group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo/{bar}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function(){
        // ...
    })->where('bar', '[0-9a-Z]+');
});
```

Or do it a bit more dynamic and add this at the bottom of your route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo/{bar}'], function($group) {
    // ...

    foreach($group->getRoutes() as $route){
        $route->where('bar', '[0-9a-Z]+');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

I'm using laravel 5.5. I had same problem and find this question in search.
I've tried to use the solution defined by @lukasgeiter and faced a problem:
The value of
`$group->getRoutes()`
was not only the routes of current group.
 
But I fixed my problem by specifying condition in route group definition.

```
Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'foo/{bar}',
        'where'  => ['bar' => '[0-9a-Z]+']
    ],
    function() {

    // ...

});
```

And it worked for me :)

Comment: This is the correct way you want to do this with Laravel 5/6 - confirmed it works as stated.

Answer (score 4):

One of possible not perfect solution in my view will be

```
// Route Model Binding
Route::model('user', 'User');

// Route Constraint Pattern
Route::pattern('user', '[0-9]+');

// Route Definition
Route::get('anything/{user}', 'UserController@anyFunction');
.
.
Route::resource('user', 'UsersController');
```