# Laravel: how to limit some route parameter to specific values?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Is that possible to make `route` that accept string parameter only for specific string? Example :

```
Route::get('{user_tipe}/event', 'admin\EventC@index');
```

That the route, I want to make the `user_tipe` param is only allow to two string like `admin` and `author`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do that using [regular expression constraits](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) on your route:

```
Route::get('{user_tipe}/event', 'admin\EventC@index')->where('user_tipe', 'admin|author');
```

`admin|author` is a simple regular expression that will match either the string `admin` or `author`

*UPDATE*

[Here you can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874866/how-to-set-regular-expression-parameter-constraints-for-routegroup-in-laravel) how to use the route param constraints when using `Route::group`

Comment: nice, the regular expression for routes is the best way for that

Comment: Thanks @moppo. I tried same approach on the 
`Route::group(['prefix' => '/{lang}'], function(){
 //Routes for en and fr goes here. 
})->where('lang', 'en|fr');` 
but i got this error `Call to a member function where() on null`. Please, any heads up to solve my worry?